# How can I catch event on loaded pages with jQuery? ( on() not working)

Tags: jquery, events

I've a page in which I use the method `Load()` of jQuery to load some PHP code.

In my base page, I have the following jQuery code:

```
    $('.writeLink').on('click',function (e) {
    //alert("ok");
    var dataurl1 = $(this).attr("par1");
    var dataurl2 = $(this).attr("par2");
    if (dataurl1 != null)
    {
        $('#txtTo').val(dataurl1);
        $('#imgTo').attr('src',dataurl2);
        $('#writeModel').modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
    dialog.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
        dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

I have the `#writemodel` div on my base page.

The loaded PHP creates some divs with the `.writeLink` class, that *should* initiate the click event, but don't. I tried to use the `.on()` jQuery event but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$("#writemodel").on("click", ".writeLink", function(e){
    //do stuff
});
```

The click event is captured by the parent container, but the function executes only if the event originated in one of the '.writeLink' divs.